# How to download recaptcha in Selenium?

Tags: java, selenium, phantomjs

I need to download the image of recaptcha to my computer, but how can i do this through Selenium?

I mean i need screenshot of this block:

[image: recaptcha]

Comment: @mrfreester I disagree: OP needs screenshot of a given element, see another duplicate proposition above.

Comment: @Vaviloff I think you're most likely right, unless OP clarifies differently, I'll flag per your suggestion.